# I am Unable to use my own annotation

Tags: java, reflection

Error when using my own annotations, can any one help mein this problem
This is my following Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)


public @interface CanRun {

}
```

This is one of my class showing an error in the in place of annotation , can any one explain & solve...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class AnnotationRunner {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    @CanRun
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }

    @CanRun
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("method3");
    }

    public void method4() {
        System.out.println("method4");
    }

    public void method5() {
        System.out.println("method5");
    }

}
```

This is main class which uses this annotation

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationRunner runner = new AnnotationRunner();
        Method[] methods = runner.getClass().getMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            CanRun annos = method.getAnnotation(CanRun.class);
            if (annos != null) {
                try {
                    method.invoke(runner);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what exactly the error is? Is the annotation not found or it can't be applied at this place or something else?

Comment: You annotate it with `@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)` but you put the annotation at a method? Hmm :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)
```

to

```
@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to say. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need

> @Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)

if you want to annotate methods